# rails7.0.3をインストールし、ローカルにて開発環境を構築したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

■背景
https://prog-8.com/docs/ruby-env
上記プロゲートのサイトに沿って、railsインストールを試みています。

■やりたいこと
rails7.03をインストールし、ローカルにて開発環境を構築したい

■環境
M1チップ macbookpro2020
Ventura ver13.0
※環境詳細は下記参考を参照願います

■現状
`rails -v`　実行でエラーが出る
(`rails new sample_app`でも同じエラー)

※エラー文にて読み込めないと言われているetcは`gem list`では表示されている

GEMはあるのにRailsがインストールできない状態？

■既に試したこと（しかし同じエラー発生）
Homebrew, rbenv, rubyアンインストールの上、再度インストールし、ローカル環境構築試みました。

PC再起動、OSアプデ

■実際に出てるエラーメッセージ

＜抜粋＞

```
<internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError)
```

＜エラー全文＞

```
<internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- etc (LoadError)
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/processor_counter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/configuration.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/logger.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/rails:25:in `load'
from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
```

■参考
以下記載します(他確認事項あれば連絡願います)

- `ruby -v`
- `brew -v`
- `rbenv -v`
- `echo %PATH`
- `xcode-select -v`
- `which ruby`
- `which gem`
- `which openssl`
- `openssl version`
- `rbenv versions`

```
% ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin20]


brew -v
Homebrew 3.6.7
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 3e58848f149; last commit 2022-10-26)


rbenv -v
rbenv 1.2.0


echo %PATH
%PATH


xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2396.


which ruby
/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/shims/ruby


which gem
/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/shims/gem


% which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl


openssl version
LibreSSL 3.3.6


rbenv versions
system
* 3.1.2 (set by /Users/hirokinagai/.ruby-version)


gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abbrev (default: 0.1.0)
actioncable (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
actionmailbox (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
actionmailer (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
actionpack (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
actiontext (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
actionview (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
activejob (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
activemodel (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
activerecord (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
activestorage (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
activesupport (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
base64 (default: 0.1.1)
benchmark (default: 0.2.0)
bigdecimal (default: 3.1.1)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (default: 2.3.7)
cgi (default: 0.3.1)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
crass (1.0.6)
csv (default: 3.2.2)
date (default: 3.2.2)
debug (1.4.0)
delegate (default: 0.2.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.6.1)
digest (default: 3.1.0)
drb (default: 2.1.0)
english (default: 0.7.1)
erb (default: 2.2.3)
error_highlight (default: 0.3.0)
erubi (1.11.0)
etc (default: 1.3.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.1)
fiddle (default: 1.1.0)
fileutils (default: 1.6.0)
find (default: 0.1.1)
forwardable (default: 1.3.2)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.1)
globalid (1.0.0)
i18n (1.12.0)
io-console (default: 0.5.11)
io-nonblock (default: 0.1.0)
io-wait (default: 0.2.1)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.4)
irb (default: 1.4.1)
json (default: 2.6.1)
logger (default: 1.5.0)
loofah (2.19.0)
mail (2.7.1)
marcel (1.0.2)
matrix (0.4.2)
method_source (1.0.0)
mini_mime (1.1.2)
minitest (5.15.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.1)
net-ftp (0.1.3)
net-http (default: 0.2.0)
net-imap (0.2.3)
net-pop (0.1.1)
net-protocol (default: 0.1.2)
net-smtp (0.3.1)
nio4r (2.5.8)
nkf (default: 0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.13.9 arm64-darwin)
observer (default: 0.1.1)
open-uri (default: 0.2.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.1)
openssl (default: 3.0.0)
optparse (default: 0.2.0)
ostruct (default: 0.5.2)
pathname (default: 0.2.0)
power_assert (2.0.1)
pp (default: 0.3.0)
prettyprint (default: 0.1.1)
prime (0.1.2)
pstore (default: 0.1.1)
psych (default: 4.0.3)
racc (default: 1.6.0)
rack (2.2.4)
rack-test (2.0.2)
rails (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
railties (7.0.4, 7.0.3)
rake (13.0.6)
rbs (2.1.0)
rdoc (default: 6.4.0)
readline (default: 0.0.3)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.4)
reline (default: 0.3.0)
resolv (default: 0.2.1)
resolv-replace (default: 0.1.0)
rexml (3.2.5)
rinda (default: 0.1.1)
rss (0.2.9)
ruby2_keywords (default: 0.0.5)
securerandom (default: 0.1.1)
set (default: 1.0.2)
shellwords (default: 0.1.0)
singleton (default: 0.1.1)
stringio (default: 3.0.1)
strscan (default: 3.0.1)
syslog (default: 0.1.0)
tempfile (default: 0.1.2)
test-unit (3.5.3)
thor (1.2.1)
time (default: 0.2.0)
timeout (default: 0.2.0)
tmpdir (default: 0.1.2)
tsort (default: 0.1.0)
typeprof (0.21.2)
tzinfo (2.0.5)
un (default: 0.2.0)
uri (default: 0.11.0)
weakref (default: 0.1.1)
websocket-driver (0.7.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
yaml (default: 0.2.0)
zeitwerk (2.6.1)
zlib (default: 2.1.1)
```